# OpenCV 3 KNearest

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to convert opencv2 code to opencv3, and I have a problem with KNearest. My first error was in this line of code

```
cv::KNearest kNearest = cv::KNearest();
```

and I changed it with

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::KNearest> kNearest = cv::ml::KNearest::create();
```

but than I got a problem in this line

```
kNearest.train(matTrainingImages, matClassificationFloats);
```

and I don't know how to solve it, so can somebody help me, please.

Comment: post the error message, probably should be `kNearest->train(...)`

Comment: glad it works, posted as an answer then

Answer (score 2):

Since `kNearest` is a `cv::Ptr` object, you need to access it using `->` operator:

```
kNearest->train(matTrainingImages, matClassificationFloats);
```